# How to find a point on the tangent line whos length is 1?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, circles

im trying to figure out a formula to find the point(x,y) on a tangent line whos length is between 0 and 1 while it rotates around the unit circle uniformly, so the point would either be right on the center where it touches the circle or between 0.5 to the left and 0.5 to the right, thank you for your time

[image: unit circle and tangent line]

Comment: The point can be always on the center of the line while the line is always tangent to the circle and rotating uniformly. Or the point can start from (1,0) while the line is vertical at x = 1, however it can not rotate all the circle because of the length of the line. I didn't get it.

Comment: the line stays length 1 and rotates around the circle from the center of the line, not the line bending around the circle

Comment: if the tangent of the line is the only 1 place it touches the circle than it can rotate the circumference only touching the circle at one point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your radial vector is $\vec r=(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)$, then you can express the tangent as a vector normal to that: $\vec s=(-\sin \alpha, \cos \alpha)$.

I think what you are asking for is a parameterization along the tangent: $\vec r + t \vec s$ - in this case $t \in [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ would do just that.

Comment: so if the point on the line is .9 where does that fall on the x and y axis of outside the circle, think you can break it down like that for me, thanks

Comment: Might be worth your while to plot that function somehow to get a feel for it. If we use your figure as an example so that $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{4}$ we get $(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\{(1,1)+t*(-1,1)\}$. So, at $t=0$ you get the point where the tangent touches the circle, at $t=0.5$ you get (since $|\vec s|=1$) $(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: ... or for 0.9 (which corresponds to $t=-0.4$ in this formulation): $(x,y)\approx (0.99, 0.42)$.

Comment: im trying to understand, can you do it so the angle is 0 and the center point of the line is at (1,0) and then 0.9 on the line, i dont understand {(1,1) + t *(-1,1)} the notation in point form?

Comment: $(x,y)=(\cos\alpha-t\sin\alpha, \sin\alpha+t\cos\alpha)$. For $\alpha=0$ that is $(x,y)=(1,t)$ - a vertical line centered at $(1,0)$ for $t=0$ (measuring the line $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ around that point). Still, your $0.9$ corresponds to $t=-0.4$, so $(x,y)=(1,-0.4)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: understood, hey thanks alot, i really appreciate it